# What Weather Monitor (weather station) software is available?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, weather

Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10

Need a application and or recommendation for a monitoring system. It will be set up locally and used to record essential data, reports to channels such as: The Weather Channel - Weather Underground - AccuWeather etc.

Comment: I understand where it reports TO, but... where it get Data FROM locally (soft)

Comment: Locally- as stated above. IE; From the instruments measuring the source, rainfall, humidity, air-speed, temperature. All the shell input data.

Comment: I know the hardware, i mean it have a Software part?, its working and storing data locally already?, whats the Format of the Data?

Comment: Can you provide that answer? No monitor, No system, Not yet!

Comment: @blueXrider I am very interested in this? Are you looking to have a little station on top of your place? In college I worked a project that was passed through PHP and mySQL using a crystal report - - I imagine something the same is possible using a different reporting software...

Comment: @RSX-1327 yes, however I have not yet found what I am looking for

Comment: I would need to know what type of data is posted, and in what format; usually these "home" devices just port data to a pretty GUI. Sounds like you need a device that posts to a CSV so you can import it into a module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a few options that might be of use/interest:

- [weeWX](http://www.weewx.com/)
- [wvview](http://www.wviewweather.com/)
- [MeteoStationNM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/meteostaionnm/)
- [Weather Station Datalogger](http://wmrx00.sourceforge.net/)

At least a couple have Ubuntu packages available from their site, and most support some sort of export in format suitable for WeatherUnderground or CWOP.

Comment: Nice, I will look into your recommendations. Thanks

Comment: I have installed `gnome-weather` from `Software Center`. This is for multiple locations but for 3 days (morning, evening) only. Temperature in C/F and clouds/sun/rain info.

Answer (score 2):

There is one more program for Ubuntu. That is Weather Display.

Download [Weather display](http://www.weather-display.com/downloadfiles/WeatherD.tar.gz) Then you can install it with

```
tar -xvf WeatherD.tar.gz
cd WeatherD
chmod +x GoWeather.sh
./GoWeather.sh
```

**Note**: to you have proper installation you have to install these packages

```
  sudo apt-get install libgtk1.2 libgdk-pixbuf2
```

Few other good programs are there which are available in software centre too.

1.AWeather.

2.Stormcloud(Commercial product of $3:00).

you can have them by filling the search field with their names.Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For robust/reliable result, you need `data acquisition` solution.

Do a Google search with that term and you will find some result. Many of them will provide free SDK/Library, you just need to buy the hardware. [This](http://www.dataq.com/temperature-data-logger/temperature-data-logger.html) is one with temperature equipment.(OK, I am lazy here, that is the 1st one come up on the search :P)

There are also free Linux data acquisition library/SDK, but you will have to check what hardware they are supporting. [Comedi](http://www.comedi.org/) is one of them.